# Fn+F2 does not UNMUTE

Tags: linux, xorg, audio, laptop, key-mapping

I am using Lubuntu 11.10 (original, not Ubuntu + LXDE) on a Vaio VPCEG series. After install of some network manager, my key `Fn+F2` got a different function.

It's printed on it the blue symbol for MUTE. Well, it was working.

Now, if the sound is ON and I press `Fn+F2`, the sound will be muted and the icon on the bar is changed.

But I am not able to UNMUTE. If I press again, nothing happens.

Below is the result from `xev`. Helps are welcome. Thanks.

```
KeyRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
root 0xb7, subw 0x0, time 2129709, (-432,-17), root:(667,296),
state 0x0, keycode 121 (keysym 0x1008ff12, XF86AudioMute), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem (posted by me) re-installing the `alsa-utils`. I don't know if this is the solution, but it works for me.